# How to create an image with Matlab (basic)

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, rgb

Can someone give me an idea on how to create a simple image using Matlab.

For example, an RGB image?

I am new to this so would like some simple code to get me started.

I believe I need to create a matrix, with the entries corresponding to colour intensity. Is this correct?

Thank you

Comment: @David Hi, this was my first post here. I am not sure what was wrong with my question?

Comment: @David I have had a look at previous answers and none of them provided me with the information I need. I need some basic info to get started as I am new to this.

Comment: Look at the documentation for `image`. Stackoverflow is not the place for very simple questions such as this that can be solved by simply searching the documentation.

Comment: @David OK, well I won't ask questions like that again. What is 'the documentation'?

Comment: The Matlab help... Type `doc image` into the Matlab command window....

Answer (score 0):

although this is well explained in https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/image-types-in-the-toolbox.html, just for starters, you could try this:

```
I = randi([0 255],100,100,'uint8'); % this is the red plane of your RGB image
I(:,:,2) = randi([0 255],100,100,'uint8'); % this is the green plane
I(:,:,3) = randi([0 255],100,100,'uint8'); % blue plane
```

'randi' creates random numbers, and the way it is specified here, the range is from 0 to 255, the type is an unsigned integer, of depth 8, and there are 100 x 100 pixels in each frame. Now, use 'image' or 'imshow' to show this image.

```
imshow(I)
```

Now you will see a random set of colors, each of which is defined by the R, G and B plane values. For example,

```
I(1,1,1) % is the red plane pixel, at the (1,1) location.
I(1,1,2) % is the (1,1) green pixel
I(50,50,3) % is the blue pixel at (50,50), and so on.
```

Comment: thanks very much for this. I have an end goal of creating some mathematical-based art so the random property could be a good starting point